# How can I make GraphQL support int8 type in Supabase?

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, supabase

I'm creating a simple CRUD app to learn GraphQL and am using a Supabase postgres instance. All queries and mutations work fine except for one thing, I can't get the id field from my schemas because they are of type `int8` on Supabase, and GraphQL only supports `Int`.

I'm getting this error when I try to get a row's `id` using the gql `Int` type in my type defs: `GraphQLError: Int cannot represent non-integer value: 1`

I know the solution involves creating a custom scalar type as in [this example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/custom-scalars/#example-the-date-scalar), but I'm not sure how to implement this type. Also, I cannot change this on Supabase's side, so I must find a way to handle this in gql. How can I handle this type in GraphQL?

TypeDefs:

```js
export const typeDefs = `#graphql
  type User {
    id: Int!
    name: String!
    email: String!
    age: Int!
    verified: Boolean!
  }

  type Todo {
    id: Int!
    title: String!
    description: String!
  }

  type Query {
    # users queries
    getAllUsers: [User]
    getUser(email: String!): User
    # todo queries
    getAllTodos: [Todo]
    getTodo(id: String!): Todo
  }

  type Mutation {
    createUser(name: String!, email: String!, age: Int!): User
    createTodo(title: String!, description: String!): Todo
  }
`;
```

Resolvers:

```js
import { GraphQLScalarType } from 'graphql';
import { prisma } from '../lib/db.js';

const BigInt = new GraphQLScalarType({
// how do I implement this type?
});

export const resolvers = {
  BigInt,
  Query: {
    getAllUsers() {
      return prisma.user.findMany();
    },
    getUser(parent, args) {
      return prisma.user.findUnique({
        where: {
          email: args.email,
        },
      });
    },
    getAllTodos() {
      return prisma.todo.findMany();
    },
    getTodo(parent, args) {
      return prisma.todo.findUnique({
        where: {
          id: args.id,
        },
      });
    },
  },

  // parent, arge are other arguments that get passes to resolvers automatically
  Mutation: {
    createUser(parent, args) {
      return prisma.user.create({
        data: args,
      });
    },
    createTodo(parent, args) {
      return prisma.todo.create({
        data: args,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by using the [graphql-type-ints](https://www.npmjs.com/package/graphql-type-ints) package. You can just install it and then add the type you need to your schemas and resolvers. However, I don't quite understand why we need to do this. If someone could explain why Supabase uses int8 and that doesn't conform to graphql's Int I would appreciate it.